# Build Android Applications Based on FFmpeg getting Error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have download code this [link](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/)

Import this project and convert it in to C / C ++ native project.

And also set Builder Settings to Build Command

```
bash C:\tools\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build
```

After run project then i am getting below **Error**.

```
make: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop. FFmpegTest

C:\tools\android-ndk-r5b\build\core\prebuilt-library.mk
```

I am develop above application in **Windows 7 64 bit** and **Eclipse Juno**.

Please guide me to resolved my Error.

Thanks

Comment: on windows 7 are u using cygwin to compile ffmpeg?

Comment: how to compile cygwin this project? please guide me.

Comment: first install `cygwin` on your system which provide you Linux environment to compile ffmpeg.

Comment: i have already install cygwin version 1.7.16(0.262/5/3). but how to complie ffmpeg that i don't know.

Comment: @imran khan can you please guide me?

Comment: Nik i have compiled ffmpeg in an sample project if you want then leave your emailid id i will send you. because this is not easy task to compile. and what you want to do with ffmpeg?

Comment: @imran khan thanks for your help my email id :- vachhaninikhil@gmail.com. i wants to streaming video.

Comment: hi Nik,you have done or still   need to compile FFMPEG?

Comment: @imran khan sorry for late reply .. i am still need to compile FFMPEG.

Comment: but using Openvc live streaming  is working perfectly on my end you have any issue in streaming  camera using Opencv?

Comment: my requirement is play video from my android phone and stream this video to server and send this to another my friends same time. so need to integration Red5 server to integration for stream video.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to compile ffmpeg for Android following the link you have posted (though I've heard others did succeed) same as I was never able to compile ffmpeg for Android under windows.

I have easily compiled ffmpeg **under ubuntu** using the following code

http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/.

Just go to

`dolphin-player/p/native/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-0.11.1` and run `build_android_r8.sh` from there

Once compiled under unix you can then use the resulting *.so under windows.

You can emulate unix under windows using something like the free [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

You can avoid compiling altogether by grabbing one of dolphin-player's apks (suitable for your architecture) renaming it into zip and extracting libffmeg.so from there.